# Change Status bar's style on android auto

Tags: android, android-auto

I'm trying to make the status bar (in car's screen) to be transparent in my Android Auto app. I saw in the style guideline here [link](https://developers.google.com/cars/design/android-auto/product-experience/system-ui/status-bar) that developers are allow to do it but i can't find any document about how.
Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following piece of code inside your `onCreate` method.

```js
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
  Window w = getWindow();
  w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using setStatusBarColor Method**

This method can be only used in the above API Level 21. Officially status bar color is not supporting below API Level 21. Although, Here we added an if condition.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        Window window = this.getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_transparent_color));
    }
```